# Criar links com um nome de uma tabela mysql e mostrar o seu conteúdo noutra página. É possível?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou a tentar criar uma página em php que vai buscar o nome de várias tabelas a uma database, mostra os nomes das tabelas e cria um link para cada tabela. Assim que o utilizador clicar no link, ele é levado para outra página onde é mostrado o conteúdo dessa tabela em que ele clicou. O problema é que não estou a ver uma forma de mostrar os nomes das tabelas e criar os links automaticamente.
Alguém pode dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 5):

Há algumas formas de pegar o nome das tabelas, como

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

ou

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'NOME_DO_SCHEMA';
```

Com isso você pode montar um link como `/conteudoTabela.php?tabela=NOME_DA_TABELA`.

Comment: +1: Se for usar com várias databases, a segunda query é melhor. Se for usar uma database só, a segunda query pode consumir recursos demais, utilize a primeira.

Comment: Lembrando também do SHOW DATABASES

Answer (score 0):

Tenta:

```
<?php
$dbname = 'mysql_dbname';

if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Tabela: <a href='show_data.php?table=".$row[0]."'<br />";
}

?>
```

**show_data.php**

```
<?php
$db = 'nome_database';

$c = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
$b = mysql_select_db($db, $c);

$tabela = $_GET['table'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tabela."");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

echo $data['campo1'];
}
?>
```